# How do I use HP's UFT with Eclipse's EMF Client Platform?

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft, eclipse-emf, leanft

I have an existing software system in pure Java (1.8, currently 32 bit), using Eclipse's EMF Client Platform. Some modules are opened in normal web browsers like IE, Chrome etc. while others are loaded into an Eclipse client as Eclipse plugins. We're using Eclipse Mars.

We're looking to automate our testing with HP's UFT, so we're trying it out for the first time with a freshly downloaded trial version. We easily figured out how to use UFT with modules that are opened in a web browser from a tutorial I found online.

However, we're unable to say the same for the part of the system opened in the Eclipse client. My PM did a little preliminary research and some say there are compatibility issues. Right now I'm investigating this in-depth with the objective to get it working if possible. I Google'd with the terms UFT, Eclipse plugin, and/or EMF Client Platform without useful result.

As someone using this tool for the first time, I'm looking for help from those with experience in the community. Do you know any tutorial, documentation, any material that can assist me, whether to solve the problem outright or at least to help me understand the relevant parts of the UFT tool?

I understand LeanFT is installed with UFT, so I am open to using it as an alternative. Thanks!